# Getting a Ballerina Build warning detected conflicting jars

Tags: wso2, ballerina

I'm getting the following warning and how can I get rid of it?

```
Generating executable
        warning: Detected conflicting jar files:
                'netty-buffer-4.1.86.Final.jar' dependency of 'ballerinax/redis' conflict with 'netty-buffer-4.1.94.Final.jar' dependency of 'ballerina/http'
                'netty-codec-4.1.86.Final.jar' dependency of 'ballerinax/redis' conflict with 'netty-codec-4.1.94.Final.jar' dependency of 'ballerina/http'
                'netty-common-4.1.86.Final.jar' dependency of 'ballerinax/redis' conflict with 'netty-common-4.1.94.Final.jar' dependency of 'ballerina/http'
                'netty-handler-4.1.86.Final.jar' dependency of 'ballerinax/redis' conflict with 'netty-handler-4.1.94.Final.jar' dependency of 'ballerina/http'
                'netty-resolver-4.1.86.Final.jar' dependency of 'ballerinax/redis' conflict with 'netty-resolver-4.1.94.Final.jar' dependency of 'ballerina/http'
                'netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar' dependency of 'ballerinax/redis' conflict with 'netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar' dependency of 'ballerina/http'
                'cosmosdb-native-4.1.1.jar' dependency of 'ballerinax/azure_cosmosdb' conflict with 'redis-2.4.0.jar' dependency of 'ballerinax/redis'
        target/bin/redis_fossa.jar
```

Comment: https://central.ballerina.io/ballerinax/redis/2.5.1 is released with the fix (updated netty version)

Comment: Chanuka- Could you please check and let us know (by posting here) whether this is working now